# How to understand differences in paternal haplogroups from different companies?

Tags: dna, y-dna, haplogroup

23andme (version 1) gives a man's paternal haplogroup as j2a1b1*, which is equivalent to J-M92 (YCC 2002/2008 shorthand), according to [the table Phylogenetic history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplogroup_J-M172#Phylogenetic_history) contained in the article "Haplogroup J-M172" at Wikipedia. Family Tree DNA (Y-DNA 111) gives the same man's paternal haplogroup as J-M172. How should these differences be interpreted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are effectively the same result with different levels of granularity / detail.

There are a couple things to keep in mind in regards to Y Haplogroups in general and the four main things are to keep in mind are:

1. Granularity / resolution of specific testing services and
   specific tests you purchase.
2. The Y-Tree is currently being updated monthly as more people are tested and new discoveries are made.
3. There are Y-STR tests (i.e. Y-37, Y-67, Y-111) and Y-SNP tests. SNP tests usually provide greater depth into your Haplogroup and Y-STR tests currently are better for Genealogical History Timeframe matching with distant ancestors.
4. There is the older style naming convention used by 23andMe.com and Y-Search that worked when there were less branches and depth but with increasingly complexity and depth of results the shorthand version is now the standard and expects you reference the [current Y-tree](http://isogg.org/tree/) to find the placement of the shorthand in the larger tree.

The very high level J-M172 simply means = J2 which is a little surprising they only were able to determine J2 from a Y-111 ... but you would get a much more in-depth result from further SNP testing on there (even more than 23andMe).

The 23andMe Haplogroup group is based on Y-SNPs (not Y-STR) and provided a little further detail with j2a1b1* = [M92, M260/Page14](http://isogg.org/tree/ISOGG_HapgrpJ.html); which is probably similar as you would receive through a [National Geographic DNA 2.0 SNP](http://shop.nationalgeographic.com/ngs/browse/productDetail.jsp?npd&npd&productId=2003825&gsk) test processed by FamilyTreeDNA.

Looking at the [J2 tree on YFull](http://www.yfull.com/tree/J2/) it means you belong to one of the many branches under J-M92 which you will only be able to further determine through SNP testing like the Big-Y test or a SNP pack; I would recommend also looking at [my answer to this question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10357/my-father-passed-away-next-tests-on-what-remains-of-his-dna-sample?rq=1) which I have some further detail on this.

Your High Level is 
J-M172 (J2)->J-M410->J-PF4610->J-L26->J-PF5087->J-PF5116->J-L558->J-M67->J-Z500->J-M92->One of the SNP sub-branches.

There are currently about two dozen defined sub-branches under J-M92 and as more people do Big-Y tests more are likely to be defined.

[image]